# Any Google +1 button gem for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, google-plus-one

Is there any gem to insert google +1 button to your web page on rails app?

If not is there some special "rails way" of adding a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Social Buttons gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/social-buttons) provide Twitter/Facebook/Google+/Pinterest buttons.

Answer (score 2):

> any gem to insert google +1 button to your web page on rails app

No

> some special "rails way" of adding a button

No

Just use the code provided by Google. It's a single tag added to your markup, and a few lines of script to make it work. Hardly Gem-worthy:

```
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

See the [Google documentation](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/).

Comment: but there are custom snippets. And a choice of putting data in head or body etc…

Comment: None of what you're talking about suggests a Gem. Just insert the tag into your view.

Comment: You know, entering an anchor tag is not a big deal too, but `link_to` helper is quite useful. Ok, understood no gems, thank you :)

Comment: There's a big difference between `link_to` and `<g:plusone>`. The Google+ button is a *static string* that will *never change*. There is no point in a gem/helper to output the same static string every time.

Comment: As far as I understand snippet should be dynamic content

Comment: @Uko Nothing about it is static, you just output it directly as I posted it above. All the dynamic stuff happens client-side in JavaScript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6465/discussion-between-uko-and-meagar)